# How prove this inequality with $x+y+z+w=4$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z,w>0$ and such $x+y+z+w=4$ show that
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\frac{9}{3+2(y^2+z^2+w^2)}\ge \frac{32xyzw}{(xz+yw)(wx+yz)(xy+zw)}$$I tried C-S,

\begin{align}
& \sum_\text{cyc}\frac{9}{3+2(y^2+z^2+w^2)}\ge\frac{9\cdot 16}{\sum_\text{cyc}(3+2(y^2+z^2+w^2))} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{144}{12+6(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)}=\frac{24}{2+x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}
\end{align}

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: has your sum three sumands?

Comment: What is $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}$?

Comment: C-S with $(x+1)^2$ helps, but the rest is very ugly.